# What is the work experience in internship?

Tags: internship, work-experience, student

I'm a Junior student.

And I want to apply for some internships.

But, a few internships said that you must write down your work experience.

This part is a requirement.

Actually, I think it's hard for a student to have work experience.

What does that mean? Is it real work experience? or Is it include my student projects?

Sorry for my English and Thanks for taking the time for me!!

Answer (score 5):

Work experience covers any experience you have.

- It could be paying jobs. This could be related to your area of interest, or unrelated.
- It could be volunteer positions: helping at day camp, tutoring after school....
- It could be other internships.

If your choice is a blank/sparse  work history and adding something you are not sure you should include, then include it.

That means you could include interesting or relevant  student projects. It can include after school activities such as running the sound and light for the school play. These can show some work qualities.

Something is always better than blank. If they don't see anything that applies,  nothing has been lost.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Your answer will be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in school I found this very confusing as well. I was a student, how on earth did companies expect me to have relevant work experience?

At your level I would include anything even somewhat relevant and even some thing that aren't (for example, unrelated extracurriculars). If you work a part-time job unrelated to your field, include that. If you have any *relevant* personal projects, definitely include those.

For an entry-level internship, companies are not actually expecting you to have a lot of work experience to show. However your resume is the only view of you they do have. So they are simply attempting to find out what kind of a person you are before they take the time (and money) required to interview you.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful to me!! Thanks!